# Write individual listbox items into different text boxes and repeat until all text boxes are full

Tags: vb.net

I'm programming in Visual Basic.
I have one form.

Form 1 contains:
nameTextBox
addNameButton
namesListBox
generateButton

week1TextBox
week2TextBox
week3TextBox
week4TextBox

The user needs to go to Form 1 and type a name in the text box, then add the name to the List Box.  The user will add 4 names to the List Box.  So, the ListBox will contain the names:  Adam, Brenda and Carol.

When the generateButton is clicked, the 3 names have to be written to the text boxes in that order.  So week1TextBox should contain "Adam", week2TextBox should contain "Brenda", etc... but once the last name (in this case "Carol") is written into the text box, the loop should start over.  Ultimately, there may be up to 50 week text boxes (so week50TextBox).  So the loop needs to repeat over and over.

Comment: Homework? Regardless, to get help from the SO community, I would encourage you to include any code you have tried to make so far.

Comment: We're here to help you get past specific issues you have encountered while trying to solve a problem, not to give you code so that you don't have to try to solve it in the first place. As you should always do, start by forgetting that it's a programming problem. If you had to write instructions for someone to perform this task with a pen and paper, could you do it? Of course you could. That wouldn't take any programming experience. So, go ahead and do that. Once you're done, you can then write code to implement those instructions.

Answer (score 0):

As there is a lack of source code in your question, I'm really not sure exactly how the layout should look, I can only offer some advice/suggestions.

I would recommend creating your listbox control, input textbox, and button to add names to the listbox. In addition to these, though, also add a scrollable panel. (*Not sure what the exact term for that control is in VB.net; it's been a long time since I've worked with that language.*) Because it sounds like there might be a variable number of items on the panel, when the user goes to generate the list of names, I would use the following rough pseudocode:

```
Dim OutputTexts As New ArrayList ' This is only here if you want to work with these textboxes later
Private Sub CreateOutput() Handles btnGenerate.Click
    pOutputPanel.Controls.Clear()
    OutputTexts.Clear()
    Dim NextX As Integer = 0 ' Pretty much unnecessary value, but included in case you want to mess with this
    Dim NextY As Integer = 0
    For i As Integer = 0 To Convert.ToInt32(txtWeekCount.Text)
        Dim txtName As New TextBox
        txtName.Text = lbNameList.Item(i Mod lbNameList.Items.Count)
        txtName.Location = new Point(NextX, NextY) ' Play with this as necessary
        NextY += 50 ' Play with this as necessary
        OutputTexts.Add(txtName)
        pOutputPanel.Controls.Add(txtName)
    Next
End Sub
```

Again, this is very much pseudocode, so I would not encourage copying and pasting, but give it a read, make sure you understand all of it, and then try implementing something similar. There might be an easier way to do it, but I have not programmed in VB.NET in probably over 2 years (at least). Nonetheless, the most important thing in here is the following line: `lbNameList.Item(i Mod lbNameList.Items.Count)`. By `Mod`-ing your indexing variable, you will be accessing items sequentially, and then repeating from the start of the ListBox items collection once *`i`* is out of range.

I would also encourage you to dynamically generate your TextBox controls as needed rather than manually adding in 50 or more TextBox controls.